# Using delimiters to separate string into variables

Tags: c#

I have a list of string where each list item contains 6 values. Each value is separated by a comma. I want to use Split(',') to separate each value then assign each one to a variable

Do I have to use an array to create new variables, or is there a way to separate each value into existing variables?

Currently the code I have to do this is nothing but

```
foreach (String Item in ItemList)
{
    string id="";
    string slip = "";
    string qty = "";
    string itemEntered = "";
    string UOM = "";
    string desc = "";

    string[] vars = Item.Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to extract the split values by index:

```
string[] vars = line.Split(',');

string id   = vars[0];
string slip = vars[1];
string Qty  = vars[2];
string Item = vars[3];
string UOM  = vars[4];
string Desc = vars[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use an available [CSV-Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) instead of doing this manually. However, if your data never contains the separator and it's strict, your approach is fine. You just have to take the strings at the correct indices:

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
foreach (String line in ItemList)
{
    string[] vars = line.Split(',');
    if (vars.Length == 6)
    {
        int id;
        if(!int.TryParse(vars[0], out id))
            continue;
        string slip = vars[1];
        int qty;
        if(!int.TryParse(vars[2], out qty))
            continue;
        string item = vars[3];
        string uom = vars[4];
        string desc = vars[5];
        data.Add(new Data { ID = id, Slip = vars[1], Quantity = qty, Desc = desc, Item = item, UOM = uom });
    }
}
```

I have also used a custom class:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Slip { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```